# Rails 4 app shows a wrong time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, timezone

I am in California, current time is 9:36am, the app `Time.now` shows 4:36:08.
My `production.rb` setup is:

```
  config.time_zone = 'Pacific Time (US & Canada)'
  config.active_record.default_timezone = 'Pacific Time (US & Canada)'
```

I set the above, restarted the server, but still getting this wrong time. What am I overlooking?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

`Time.zone.now` should return correct time.